# Unexpectedly empty match-group value

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using a regex to grab content for a web page.  I use a similar approach for another table, and that is working well; but I have a problem with this

```
.Giocatore_ammonito = Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=""player large-link""\s*>(.+?)</td>").Groups(1).ToString
```

where `Content` comes from http://it.soccerway.com/a/block_competition_playerstats?block_id=page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9&callback_params=%7B%22round_id%22%3A%2227139%22%2C%22view%22%3A%222%22%7D&action=changeView&params=%7B%22view%22%3A2%7D.

`Groups(1).ToString` returns a blank result, but I do not understand why.

*What is wrong with the regex that I am missing?*

For completeness, here is `Content`'s value inline:

```
{"commands":[{"name":"updateContainer","parameters":{"content":"<div class=\"container-full\"><div class=\"block  clearfix block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary-wrapper\" id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1-wrapper\"><div class=\"content  \"><div id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_pagination\" class=\"pagination match-pagination clearfix\"><div class=\"nav_description\"><a rel=\"previous\" class=\"previous disabled\" id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_previous\">&laquo; precedente<\/a><a rel=\"next\" class=\"next \" id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_next\">successiva &raquo;<\/a><\/div><\/div><div class=\"block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary real-content clearfix \" id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1\"><table class=\"playerstats table\" id=\"page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_table\" data-round_id=\"27139\" data-season_id=\"0\"><thead><tr class=\"sub-head\"><th class=\"player\">Giocatore<\/th><th class=\"team\">Squadra<\/th><th class=\"number yellow-cards\"><img src=\"http:\/\/s1.swimg.net\/gsmf\/520\/img\/events\/YC.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"13\" alt=\"Cartellino giallo\" title=\"Cartellino giallo\" \/><\/th><th class=\"number red-cards\"><img src=\"http:\/\/s1.swimg.net\/gsmf\/520\/img\/events\/RC.png\" width=\"13\" height=\"13\" alt=\"Cartellino rosso\" title=\"Cartellino rosso\" \/><\/th><th class=\"number points\"><acronym title=\"Punti\">Pts<\/acronym><\/th><\/tr><\/thead><tbody><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"416\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/rafael-marquez-alvarez\/416\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 mexico_16_left\">R. M\u00e1rquez<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/hellas-verona-fc\/1277\/\" title=\"Hellas Verona\">Verona<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">5<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number points\">11<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"13870\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/facundo-sebastian-roncaglia\/13870\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 argentina_16_left\">F. Roncaglia<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/genoa-cfc\/1276\/\" title=\"Genoa\">Genoa<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">5<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number points\">11<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"148164\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/afriyie-acquah\/148164\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 ghana_16_left\">A. Acquah<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/parma-fc\/1243\/\" title=\"Parma\">Parma<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">7<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">10<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"3991\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/daniele-bonera\/3991\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">D. Bonera<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/ac-milan\/1240\/\" title=\"Milan\">Milan<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">3<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number points\">9<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"18275\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/federico-peluso\/18275\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">F. Peluso<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/us-sassuolo-calcio\/5681\/\" title=\"Sassuolo\">Sassuolo<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">6<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">9<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"4473\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/dal-belo-dias-da-silva\/4473\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 brazil_16_left\">Felipe<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/parma-fc\/1243\/\" title=\"Parma\">Parma<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number points\">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"178336\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/stefano-sturaro\/178336\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">S. Sturaro<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/genoa-cfc\/1276\/\" title=\"Genoa\">Genoa<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">5<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"4295\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/luca-cigarini\/4295\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">L. Cigarini<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/atalanta-bergamo\/1255\/\" title=\"Atalanta\">Atalanta<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">5<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"246415\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/domenico-berardi\/246415\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">D. Berardi<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/us-sassuolo-calcio\/5681\/\" title=\"Sassuolo\">Sassuolo<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">5<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"2006\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/nigel-de-jong\/2006\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 netherlands_16_left\">N. de Jong<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/ac-milan\/1240\/\" title=\"Milan\">Milan<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">8<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">0<\/td><td class=\"number points\">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"17855\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/simone-padoin\/17855\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">S. Padoin<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/juventus-fc\/1242\/\" title=\"Juventus\">Juventus<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">2<\/td><td class=\"number points\">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"61429\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/ivan-radovanovic\/61429\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 serbia_16_left\">I. Radovanovi\u0107<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/ac-chievo-verona\/1248\/\" title=\"Chievo Verona\">Chievo<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">4<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"71325\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/segundo-victor-ibarbo-guerrero\/71325\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 colombia_16_left\">V. Ibarbo<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/cagliari-calcio\/1256\/\" title=\"Cagliari\">Cagliari<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">4<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"even\" data-people_id=\"71\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/daniele-de-rossi\/71\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\">D. De Rossi<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/as-roma\/1241\/\" title=\"Roma\">Roma<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">4<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\"odd\" data-people_id=\"139596\"><td class=\"player large-link\"><a href=\"\/players\/kalidou-koulibaly\/139596\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 france_16_left\">K. Koulibaly<\/a><\/td><td class=\"team large-link\"><a href=\"\/teams\/italy\/ssc-napoli\/1270\/\" title=\"Napoli\">Napoli<\/a><\/td><td class=\"number yellow-cards\">4<\/td><td class=\"number red-cards\">1<\/td><td class=\"number points\">7<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan=\"5\">abbiamo assegnato punti per ciascun cartellino giallo (1 punto) e rosso (3 punti). Da notare che non rappresentano alcuna classifica ufficiale.<\/td><\/tr><\/tfoot><\/table><script type=\"text\/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">(function(){var table = $('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_table');Popupizer.setup(table.select('tbody td[class*=\"yellow-cards\"]'), 'player_events', { column: 'yellow_cards' });Popupizer.setup(table.select('tbody td[class*=\"red-cards\"]'), 'player_events', { column: 'red_cards' });new PopupManager(table);})();\n<\/script><\/div><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<script type=\"text\/javascript\" charset=\"utf-8\">(function() {var block = new PaginatedBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1', 'block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary', {\"page\":0,\"per_page\":15,\"round_id\":27139,\"season_id\":0});block.registerForCallbacks();block.setAttribute('has_previous_page', false);block.setAttribute('has_next_page', true);TimestampFormatter.format('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1');})();\n<\/script><\/div>\n"}},{"name":"updateCallbackParams","parameters":{"params":{"round_id":"27139","view":"2"}}}],"timestamp":"Sun, 04 Jan 2015 20:52:10 +0100"}
```

Comment: [Regex to parse HTML is a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) or whatever tool specialized to handle HTML structures

Comment: Ok but i've write a lot of code for grab the html value, and now i want only correct this; in the furure i will be use this package

Comment: The quotes seem to be escaped, try `<td class=\\""player large-link\\""\s*>(.+?)</td>`.

Comment: This is definitely on the right track, @Rawing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Overview

Continuing in the direction that @Rawing started going with his comment, there are backslash-escaping issues in the content for which the regex needs to account.

Try this instead...

```
.Giocatore_ammonito = Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=\\""player large-link\\""\s*>(.+?)<\\/td>").Groups(1).ToString
'                                                     ^^                   ^^            ^^
```

...to account for backslashes preceding the double quotes around the `class` attributes' values *and* the backslashes preceding the forward slashes in the `td` closing tags.

**Also**, you may wish to *scrub the backslash escaping that will otherwise remain* in the match-group value(s).

### Demo Code

Here is VB.NET code that shows **1)** how the updated regex works with your content and **2)** how to optionally scrub lingering backslash escaping from the match-group value(s):

```
' NOTE: content returned from the URL provided in the question
Dim Content As String = "{""commands"":[{""name"":""updateContainer"",""parameters"":{""content"":""<div class=\""container-full\""><div class=\""block  clearfix block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary-wrapper\"" id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1-wrapper\""><div class=\""content  \""><div id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_pagination\"" class=\""pagination match-pagination clearfix\""><div class=\""nav_description\""><a rel=\""previous\"" class=\""previous disabled\"" id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_previous\"">&laquo; precedente<\/a><a rel=\""next\"" class=\""next \"" id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_next\"">successiva &raquo;<\/a><\/div><\/div><div class=\""block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary real-content clearfix \"" id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1\""><table class=\""playerstats table\"" id=\""page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_table\"" data-round_id=\""27139\"" data-season_id=\""0\""><thead><tr class=\""sub-head\""><th class=\""player\"">Giocatore<\/th><th class=\""team\"">Squadra<\/th><th class=\""number yellow-cards\""><img src=\""http:\/\/s1.swimg.net\/gsmf\/520\/img\/events\/YC.png\"" width=\""13\"" height=\""13\"" alt=\""Cartellino giallo\"" title=\""Cartellino giallo\"" \/><\/th><th class=\""number red-cards\""><img src=\""http:\/\/s1.swimg.net\/gsmf\/520\/img\/events\/RC.png\"" width=\""13\"" height=\""13\"" alt=\""Cartellino rosso\"" title=\""Cartellino rosso\"" \/><\/th><th class=\""number points\""><acronym title=\""Punti\"">Pts<\/acronym><\/th><\/tr><\/thead><tbody><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""416\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/rafael-marquez-alvarez\/416\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 mexico_16_left\"">R. M\u00e1rquez<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/hellas-verona-fc\/1277\/\"" title=\""Hellas Verona\"">Verona<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">5<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">11<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""13870\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/facundo-sebastian-roncaglia\/13870\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 argentina_16_left\"">F. Roncaglia<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/genoa-cfc\/1276\/\"" title=\""Genoa\"">Genoa<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">5<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">11<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""148164\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/afriyie-acquah\/148164\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 ghana_16_left\"">A. Acquah<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/parma-fc\/1243\/\"" title=\""Parma\"">Parma<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">7<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">10<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""3991\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/daniele-bonera\/3991\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">D. Bonera<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/ac-milan\/1240\/\"" title=\""Milan\"">Milan<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">3<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">9<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""18275\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/federico-peluso\/18275\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">F. Peluso<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/us-sassuolo-calcio\/5681\/\"" title=\""Sassuolo\"">Sassuolo<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">6<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">9<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""4473\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/dal-belo-dias-da-silva\/4473\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 brazil_16_left\"">Felipe<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/parma-fc\/1243\/\"" title=\""Parma\"">Parma<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""178336\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/stefano-sturaro\/178336\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">S. Sturaro<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/genoa-cfc\/1276\/\"" title=\""Genoa\"">Genoa<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">5<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""4295\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/luca-cigarini\/4295\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">L. Cigarini<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/atalanta-bergamo\/1255\/\"" title=\""Atalanta\"">Atalanta<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">5<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""246415\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/domenico-berardi\/246415\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">D. Berardi<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/us-sassuolo-calcio\/5681\/\"" title=\""Sassuolo\"">Sassuolo<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">5<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""2006\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/nigel-de-jong\/2006\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 netherlands_16_left\"">N. de Jong<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/ac-milan\/1240\/\"" title=\""Milan\"">Milan<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">8<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">0<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">8<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""17855\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/simone-padoin\/17855\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">S. Padoin<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/juventus-fc\/1242\/\"" title=\""Juventus\"">Juventus<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">2<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""61429\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/ivan-radovanovic\/61429\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 serbia_16_left\"">I. Radovanovi\u0107<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/ac-chievo-verona\/1248\/\"" title=\""Chievo Verona\"">Chievo<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">4<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""71325\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/segundo-victor-ibarbo-guerrero\/71325\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 colombia_16_left\"">V. Ibarbo<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/cagliari-calcio\/1256\/\"" title=\""Cagliari\"">Cagliari<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">4<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""even\"" data-people_id=\""71\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/daniele-de-rossi\/71\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 italy_16_left\"">D. De Rossi<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/as-roma\/1241\/\"" title=\""Roma\"">Roma<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">4<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">7<\/td><\/tr><tr class=\""odd\"" data-people_id=\""139596\""><td class=\""player large-link\""><a href=\""\/players\/kalidou-koulibaly\/139596\/\"" class=\""flag_16 left_16 france_16_left\"">K. Koulibaly<\/a><\/td><td class=\""team large-link\""><a href=\""\/teams\/italy\/ssc-napoli\/1270\/\"" title=\""Napoli\"">Napoli<\/a><\/td><td class=\""number yellow-cards\"">4<\/td><td class=\""number red-cards\"">1<\/td><td class=\""number points\"">7<\/td><\/tr><\/tbody><tfoot><tr><td colspan=\""5\"">abbiamo assegnato punti per ciascun cartellino giallo (1 punto) e rosso (3 punti). Da notare che non rappresentano alcuna classifica ufficiale.<\/td><\/tr><\/tfoot><\/table><script type=\""text\/javascript\"" charset=\""utf-8\"">(function(){var table = $('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1_table');Popupizer.setup(table.select('tbody td[class*=\""yellow-cards\""]'), 'player_events', { column: 'yellow_cards' });Popupizer.setup(table.select('tbody td[class*=\""red-cards\""]'), 'player_events', { column: 'red_cards' });new PopupManager(table);})();\n<\/script><\/div><\/div>\n<\/div>\n<script type=\""text\/javascript\"" charset=\""utf-8\"">(function() {var block = new PaginatedBlock('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1', 'block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary', {\""page\"":0,\""per_page\"":15,\""round_id\"":27139,\""season_id\"":0});block.registerForCallbacks();block.setAttribute('has_previous_page', false);block.setAttribute('has_next_page', true);TimestampFormatter.format('page_competition_1_block_competition_playerstats_9_block_competition_playerstats_diciplinary_1');})();\n<\/script><\/div>\n""}},{""name"":""updateCallbackParams"",""parameters"":{""params"":{""round_id"":""27139"",""view"":""2""}}}],""timestamp"":""Sun, 04 Jan 2015 20:52:10 +0100""}"
' FORNOW: Output the first match group's value to the console instead of assigning it to .Giocatore_ammonito.
Dim FirstMatchGroup As String = Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=\\""player large-link\\""\s*>(.+?)<\\/td>").Groups(1).ToString
Console.WriteLine("1st match group's value")
Console.WriteLine("-----------------------")
Console.WriteLine(FirstMatchGroup & Environment.NewLine)
'.Giocatore_ammonito = Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=\\""player large-link\\""\s*>(.+?)<\\/td>").Groups(1).ToString

' NOTE: What I think you really want is a scrubbed version of the first match group's value (i.e. without all the backslash escaping).
Dim ScrubbedFirstMatchGroup As String = FirstMatchGroup.Replace("\""", """").Replace("\/", "/")
Console.WriteLine("1st match group's value (scrubbed)")
Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------")
Console.WriteLine(ScrubbedFirstMatchGroup)
```

It outputs the following:

```
1st match group's value
-----------------------
<a href=\"\/players\/rafael-marquez-alvarez\/416\/\" class=\"flag_16 left_16 mexico_16_left\">R. M\u00e1rquez<\/a>

1st match group's value (scrubbed)
----------------------------------
<a href="/players/rafael-marquez-alvarez/416/" class="flag_16 left_16 mexico_16_left">R. M\u00e1rquez</a>
```