# Regex catch space in the link

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm grab value from web page and I use this:

```
.Squadra = Regex.Match(Content, "<td class=""team large-link""\s*>(.+?)</td>").Groups(1).ToString
.Squadra = Remove_Tags(Regex.Match(.Squadra, ">(\w+)<\/a>").Groups(1).ToString)
```

you can see that `.Squadra` contains the grabbed link value, so in the next step i replace al link format and grab the only value inserted in the link.
All working good, but if I have value like this: Real Vicenza, the variable return me blank value, probably for the space between Real and Vicenza?
How to correct this? I'm trying to insert `s*` before (+w) but seems doesn't work.

Comment: possible **re-post** of [Regex return me blank variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754243/regex-return-me-blank-variable)

Comment: The two posts are nothing to do with each other.

Comment: @smathy The only difference between this regex and the dupe is the word `player` and `team`.

Comment: No, this question is about the `\w+` part of the second line of code, the first question was about the `<td` match you're referring to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `(\w+)` use `([^<]+)` - that matches all non-`<` characters, which is far less likely to fail.